# extract a value of token from a script groovy

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui, access-token, assertions

I test a request REST from soapui and I receive one response Json that contains one token (userToken) :

```
{
   "status": 200,
   "entity":    {
      "status": "SUCCESS",
      "message":       {
         "defaultMsg": "Successfully logged in.",
         "msgId": "controller.authorization.success.log.in"
      },
      "data":       {
         "userToken": "b57796e3-d9e4-49f2-9d46-481a2048ab65",
         "userName": "operateur",
         "userId": "operateur",
        }
}
```

I add this assertion in soapui for extracting the value of userToken and put it as a variable of the project:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import net.sf.*
import net.sf.json.*
import net.sf.json.groovy.*

//def ResponseMessage = testRunner.testCase.testSteps["Recuperation Jeton"].testRequest.response.contentAsString
def ResponseMessage = messageExchange.response.contentAsString
log.info("OAUTH TOCKEN :"+ResponseMessage)
def object = new JsonSlurper().parseText(ResponseMessage)
log.info ("userToken :"+object.data.userToken)



messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue( "X-AUTH-TOKEN",object.data.userToken)
```

but it doesn't work...Can you give me your advices please ?

Thanks in Advance,

Best Regards,

Comment: Please correct code sample in your question - the one you have pasted does not compile.

Comment: I changed the code for compiling

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code. Firstly, you miss proper import for `JsonSlurper` - `groovy.json.JsonSlurper`. Secondly, your path to `userToken` property is not correct - you miss `entity` in the beginning. Your script should look more or less like that:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = messageExchange.response.contentAsString
def root = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

log.info ("userToken: " + root.entity.data.userToken)

messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("X-AUTH-TOKEN", root.entity.data.userToken)
```

Comment: I tested you code suggested and I received this error: No signature of method:com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.SinglePartHttpResponse.contentAsString() is applicable for argument types:() values:[]Possible solutions :getContentAsString()

Comment: `import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import net.sf.*
import net.sf.json.*
import net.sf.json.groovy.*
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = messageExchange.response.contentAsString()
def root = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

log.info ("userToken: " + root.entity.data.userToken)

messageExchange.modelItem.testStep.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("X-AUTH-TOKEN", root.entity.data.userToken)`

Comment: I used : def json = messageExchange.response.getContentAsString()---> OK.Thank you very much Szymon.I sent you an invitation on linkedIn.Khalid

Comment: That's correct - `response.contentAsString` is equivalent of  `response.getContentAsString()`. `()` was not necessary. Did it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `Script Assertion` is being used for the *REST Request test step*.

- In order to get the response, you could simple use `context.response`.

  `log.info context.response`
- In order to set property at project level, use  `context.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('NAME', 'VALUE')`

Over all script for `Script Assertion` would be:

```
//check if there is response
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)
def token = json.data.userToken

//check if there is token
assert token, 'token is empty or null'
log.info token

//Set value at project level property
context.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue('X-AUTH-TOKEN', token)
```